# Cannot register server on pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I installed pgadmin4 and I created a new super user 'james' and gave it a password. Postgres is running:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2023-05-30 19:39:29 SAST; 1h 46min left
    Process: 1026 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1026 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 3ms
```

The first problem I have is if I try to do psql on the command line I get an error:

```
    psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433" failed: 
    FATAL:  database "james" does not exist
```

If I created the user then surely the database must exist?

The second issue I have is I cannot register a new server in pgadmin4. I get an error:

```
    Unable to connect to server: connection failed: Connection refused Is the server 
    running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

```
Host name = localhost
Port = 5432
Username = james
```

How do I fix this please?

Comment: "If I created the user then surely the database must exist?"  No.  CREATE USER and CREATE DATABASE are different commands, and do different things.

Comment: Also, 5432 and 5433 are different than one another.